# RecyclerView duplicates the same object, and I need it to display different ones

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I know the title may seem a little weird, but allow me to explain! In another activity I have a list of objects displayed using Firebase and a Recyclerview. I am able to grab the user's correctly (the Toast in my OnCreate helps me determine this), however when I try to display the "picked" objects as a new object (GroupMembers) I am getting duplicates. I think this is caused by the mGroupMembers.setName & mGroupMembers.setUsername. I'll display the code for my Adapter just to be sure there are no mistakes there. Could anybody tell me why this is occuring and why it is not displaying the chosen objects correctly with the corresponding name and username, yet the Toast does display the name and username?

Here is my custom adapter:
MembersAdapter

```
public class MembersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MembersAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<GroupMembers> mMembers;
private final int TOTAL_AMOUNT = 100; //Max amount for all seekbars.
private final List<Integer> mAllProgress = new ArrayList<>();

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView mName, mUsername, mPercent;
    private SeekBar mSeekBar;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_view_members);
        mUsername = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username_view_members);
        mPercent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.percent_text);
        mSeekBar = (SeekBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.percent_seekbar);
    }
}

//Constructor
public MembersAdapter(List<GroupMembers> members) {
    this.mMembers = members;
}

@Override
public MembersAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout_members, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    GroupMembers individual = mMembers.get(position);
    holder.mName.setText(individual.getName());
    holder.mUsername.setText(individual.getUsername());

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMembers.size();
}
}
```

And here is the OnCreate method, I've just included where I grab the extra from the other activity until where the adapter and recyclerview are used.

Here is my relevant activity:
PaymentsOptionActivity

```
public class PaymentOptionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Tag
private static String TAG = "PaymentOptionsActivity";

@Bind(R.id.name_label)
TextView mNameLabel;
@Bind(R.id.cost_label)
TextView mCostLabel;
@Bind(R.id.color_label)
TextView mColorLabel;
@Bind(R.id.recurrence_label)
TextView mRecurrenceLabel;
@Bind(R.id.name_field)
EditText mNameField;
@Bind(R.id.cost_field)
EditText mCostField;
@Bind(R.id.color_button)
Button mColorButton;
@Bind(R.id.recurrence_spinner)
Spinner mRecurrenceSpinner;
@Bind(R.id.activity_payment_options)
RelativeLayout mActivityPaymentOptions;
@Bind(R.id.members_recycler)
RecyclerView mRecyclerview;
@Bind(R.id.bottom_naviation)
BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView;

private int mSelectedColor;
private List<GroupMembers> mMembers = new ArrayList<>(); //Group Members in a List.
private GroupMembers mGroupMembers = new GroupMembers(); //Individual Group Members
private MembersAdapter mAdapter;
private String name;
private String email;
private String username;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment_options);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    initiateBottomView();

    //Extra from other activity.
    List<UserList> groupMembers = (List<UserList>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("users"); //Selected Members

    //Convert UserList -> Members
    for (UserList users : groupMembers) {
        name = users.getName();
        email = users.getEmail();
        username = users.getUsername();

        mGroupMembers.setName(name);
        mGroupMembers.setUsername(username);

        //Display who's picked for testing.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected:  " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //List<GroupMembers> now has however members were selected..
        mMembers.add(mGroupMembers);

    //RecyclerView + Adapter
    mRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAdapter = new MembersAdapter(mMembers);
    mRecyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    public void initiateBottomView() {
    mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Intent i;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_groups:
                    //Refresh
                    i = new Intent(PaymentOptionsActivity.this, PaymentsSearchActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_dashboard:
                    i = new Intent(PaymentOptionsActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_profile:
                    item.setEnabled(true);
                    i = new Intent(PaymentOptionsActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, and if there's any suggestions I should make with my code that would be appreciated as well. This is a rather large application which is why I excluded so much code to keep it relevant.

Thank you very much!

Comment: For some clarification and if anyone is curious... When testing for the users picked in the OnCreate method, I have tried `Toast.makeText(this, "Selected:  " + mGroupMembers.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`  to test whether the GroupMembers is actually setting both names, and it is! Very confused, and I know it's gotta be a simple fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
mGroupMembers.setName(name);
mGroupMembers.setUsername(username);
```

`mGroupMembers` is one object being added multiple times to the list, so your list has a collection of the exact same object, I guess showing only the last entry over and over in the `RecyclerView`.

you should not have `mGroupMembers` as an instance variable, remove it and do this instead:

```
    for (UserList users : groupMembers) {
            name = users.getName();
            email = users.getEmail();
            username = users.getUsername();

            GroupMembers groupMembers = new GroupMembers();
            groupMembers.setName(name);
            groupMembers.setUsername(username);

            //Display who's picked for testing.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Selected:  " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //List<GroupMembers> now has however members were selected..
            mMembers.add(groupMembers);
}
```

Or something to this effect, so you create a list of individual GroupMembers rather than a list referencing the same GroupMembers object.

Comment: Yes! This solved my issue. It makes so much sense...for some odd reason I thought that it would iterate, add the object to the list, and then reset to add a new object, but I did not realize what it was ACTUALLY doing. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, sometimes you have to be careful with setters as it does expose your Objects to mutability.  If you're never going to change the object once created remove the setters and just create a constructor for the class that excepts its parameters/arguments.